# Site dropdown menu does not work in IE8 compatibility mode

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, suckerfish

I am working on a site that has a menu that looks great in new browsers, and even IE8 on vista, however in `IE8 compatibility` mode or in XP for example, the navigation does not work.

I've made a jsfiddle here to see what I mean (sorry, am in a hurry; hover over the "result" part and you'll see the dropdown in action)

http://jsfiddle.net/K3PFd/

It just doesn't work in compatibility mode or I'm assuming older versions of IE.  Of course the client is using IE8 which is why I have to fix this...

Can you PLEASE help?

Comment: Just leave it the way I edited it - it'll be easier for the people answering. Also keep in mind that [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) doesn't work for IE 9 compatibility mode

Comment: thanks, sorry about that.  But yeah, IE8 is the main culprit.